# How can i pass object one component from another component in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two components DialogOverviewExample and DialogOverviewExampleDialog . I have 'Element' object in DialogOverviewExample  and i want to pass this Element
to DialogOverviewExampleDialog  how can i pass this

The below object store in DialogOverviewExample component

```
Element = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'}

];
```

I want this to be print on DialogOverviewExample   component

[Project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-okgwc1?file=app/dialog-overview-example.ts)

Check the above link for my component code.help me out

Comment: this question should be about angular material not angular specifically

Comment: Have a look there https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component-

Answer (score 0):

On your `openDialog` function wouldn’t it be just passing the `Element` to the `data`?

```
data: this.Element
```

Or am I missing some detail in your question?

If you want to pass also the other details you have in the code it would become something like

```
data: { element: this.Element, name: this.name, animal: this.animal }
```

Comment: i want Element should be print in DialogOverviewExampleDialog Component

Comment: Your question is asking how pass the object from on component to the other

Comment: if these data comig from api that time what can i do??

Comment: You have to read the data from the api to a variable and then pass it to the data property of the dialog, as suggested